# Can i transfer my wsl ubuntu installation to a usb and run it from there?

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running out of space on the c drive of a shared work windows computer. I am currently running ubuntu using wsl downloaded in the c drive and I'm hoping to move it to free up some space in the drive.

If i copied the installation into a usb stick, would i be able to run this from the usb stick on the windows computer via wsl? That is, would i be able to access the linux installation virtually whilst still being booted into windows, as opposed to booting directly into linux as you can using a bootable usb.

If this is possible, would i be able to do the same on different windows PCs with wsl installed? And further, how would this effect my ability to run an ssh server from the ubuntu installation?

Comment: WSL is an installed App like other Apps.  I do not believe WSL has a portable version. Accordingly you cannot do what you are trying to do here

Comment: WSL does not have a portable version nor can it be made into one since it’s (now) a UWP application before of course it was an optional feature of Windows. WSL like all UWP can be installed on another drive.

Comment: alright, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

> I am running out of space on the c drive of a shared work windows
> computer.

WSL is a small type of virtual machine and uses space similar to a small virtual machine.

Accordingly, and since WSL does not lend itself to being a portable installation, your best approach for the medium and longer term would be to install a much larger drive C: